# Debugging QML Qt-Creator

Tags: c++, qt, debugging, qt-creator

I'm working on Qt-Cretor for the first time and when I debug my project, that's what I get:

```
Warning: QML Debugger: No application output received in time, trying to connect ... (no active run control)
Warning: Could not connect to the in-process QML debugger.
No application output received in time (no active run control)
Warning: NOTE: ENGINE RUN FAILED (no active run control)
Warning: Run failed. (no active run control)
Warning: State changed from EngineRunRequested(7) to EngineRunFailed(8) (no active run control)
```

I activated the QML debugger on Qt-Creator. My last try was modify the `PATH` with:

```
QMLJSDEBUGGER_PATH=D:/qt/5.8.0_vs100/qtc-qmldbg
```

But this didn't work - probably because I didn't write it correctly?